# Order by the latest (most recent) related model [Laravel]

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I have the following relations:

- Forum `hasMany` Thread (`threads()`)
- Thread `hasMany` Post (`posts()`)
- Thread `belongsTo` User (`user()`)
- Post `belongsTo` User (`user()`)

Currently, in my `ThreadsController@index` I have the following:

```
public function index()
{
    $threads = $this->forum->threads()
        ->approved()
        ->withCount(['posts AS approved_replies' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('posts.approved', true)->where('posts.is_starting_thread', false);
        }])
        ->with(['posts' => function ($query) { // Posts
            $query->approved()
                ->with('user') // Author of post
                ->latest();
            }]
        )
        ->with('user') // Author of thread
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(20); 

    return view('forums.threads.index')->with([
        'forum' => $this->forum, 'threads' => $threads
    ]);
}
```

My `index.blade.php` should show the listing of **threads** in which for each *thread* there will be:

- its author (that's why I have `->with('user')`)
- number of replies (that's why I have `>withCount(['posts AS approved_replies' => function ($query) { ...`)
- Date of the newest (latest) post and its author. That's why:

  ```
      ->with(['posts' => function ($query) { // Posts
          $query->approved()
              ->with('user') // Author of post
              ->latest(); // LATEST first
          }]
      )
  ```

  ... because then in `index.blade.php` I can access the latest post of each thread in the following way:

  ```
  @foreach ($threads as $thread) 
      {{ $thread->posts->first()->created_at; }}
      {{ $thread->posts->first()->user->username; }}
  @endforeach
  ```

The problem with this code is that *threads* are sorted by their `created_at`, not by the most recent post. What I want to achieve is to order *threads* by the latest (most recent) *post*, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. It's not particularly pretty but should do the job

```
$this->forum->threads()
    ->approved()
    ->join('posts', 'posts.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
    ->selectRaw('threads.*, MAX(posts.created_at) AS latest_post_at')
    ->groupBy('threads.id')
    ->orderByDesc('latest_post_at')
    ->withCount(['posts AS approved_replies' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('posts.approved', true)->where('posts.is_starting_thread', false);
    }])
    ->with(['posts' => function ($query) { // Posts
        $query->approved()
            ->with('user') // Author of post
            ->latest();
        }]
    )
    ->with('user')
    ->paginate(20);
```

It does a `join` as the other answer suggests, and then `groups` by thread, using `MAX` aggregate function to keep the latest date per group of posts.

#### Edit:

```
$this->forum->threads()
    ->approved()
    ->join('posts', 'posts.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
    ->select('threads.*', 'posts.created_at AS latest_post_at')
    ->whereNotExists(function ($subquery) {
        return $subquery->from('posts AS later_posts')
            ->whereRaw('later_posts.thread_id = posts.thread_id')
            ->whereRaw('later_posts.created_at > posts.created_at');
    })
    ->orderByDesc('latest_post_at')
    ->withCount(['posts AS approved_replies' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('posts.approved', true)
              ->where('posts.is_starting_thread', false);
    }])
    ->with(['posts' => function ($query) { // Posts
        $query->approved()
            ->with('user') // Author of post
            ->latest();
    }])
    ->with('user')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: One question - If I understood Laravel Documentation well - it is not recommended to use `paginate()` on results that were grouped with `groupBy()`? Or I didn't understand well that? :) It seems that it works (need to do few more tests before accepting this answer).

Comment: @PeraMika interesting, I had never seen that notice in the docs.. Try this updated code instead. I have actually used this kind of pattern for some queries like these before. Also, it reads a bit nicer, IMO

Comment: It looks that both solutions work - the first solution with `join` works OK with `paginate()`, not sure why but my guess is because you are grouping by the **id** of _thread_ (`->groupBy('threads.id')`) and therefore pagination works fine. I guess that in the Laravel documentation that notice relates to grouping by other columns that are not primary key (id)... but I'm just guessing. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting `You may award your bounty in 17 hours.`, so I'll do it after 17 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join()`:

```
$threads = Thread::join('posts as p', 'p.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
    ->where('forum_id', $this->forum->id)
    ->approved()
    ->withCount(['posts AS approved_replies' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('posts.approved', true)->where('posts.is_starting_thread', false);
    }])
    ->with(['posts' => function ($query) { // Posts
        $query->approved()
            ->with('user') // Author of post
            ->latest();
        }]
    )
    ->with('user') // Author of thread
    ->latest('p.created_at')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it now lists the same threads as many times as there are joined posts (as there are posts with `'p.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id'`). For example, if there is a thread with `id=5` and there are **8** posts with `thread_id=5`, then this thread will be displayed **8** times.